# Imagemagick shows compound letter as splitted

Tags: unicode, utf-8, fonts, imagemagick

When I try to draw text using imagemagick compound letters show as splitted. For example the word `ഉത്തരം` shows as `ഉത് തരം` without space in it.
PS: I can't write here without space as it will show as normal compound letter.
My Sublime text editor also have this problem. But in Visual studio code, it works correctly. The commands I tried below:

```
magick      -size 1040x1310     gradient:tomato-steelblue     -font Meera      -pointsize 50     -fill white     -gravity center  -bordercolor White -border 20x20   -draw "text 0,0 'ഉത്തരം'"     image.png
```

```
magick      -size 1040x1310     gradient:tomato-steelblue     -font Meera      -pointsize 50     -fill white     -gravity center  -bordercolor White -border 20x20   caption:'ഉത്തരം'     image.png
```

```
magick      -size 1040x1310     gradient:tomato-steelblue     -font Meera      -pointsize 50     -fill white     -gravity center  -bordercolor White -border 20x20   label:'ഉത്തരം'     image.png
```

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-28 Q16 x86_64
Platform: Ubuntu

Previously I was using IM version 6 of 2017 build, now I upgraded to latest manually. Still `convert --version` shows 6 but `magick --version` and `magick convert --version` shows latest. I also tried above commands with `magick convert`.

Comment: What font are you using?  What is your ImageMagick version and platform? What was your ImageMagick command line?

Comment: I added more informations. Is that sufficient?

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode. Put your text into a UTF-8 compatible text file and use @textfile in your -draw command. Does it fail that way? It could just be the glyphs are bad for that font.

Comment: Still it gives same old result. You can see font details [here](https://smc.org.in/fonts/meera) and [here](https://smc.org.in/fonts/)

Comment: I used below code `magick convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48           -font Meera label:@words.utf8   label_utf8.gif`. Also I tried `magick convert -size 360x360 xc:white -font "Meera" -pointsize 12 -fill black -draw @words.utf8 image.png` which throw error like `non-conforming drawing primitive definition `�' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4474`

Comment: try `-draw 'text x,y @words.utf'` where x,y are actual coordinates. But I would recommend using either label: or caption: or possibly -annotate in place of -draw. I am not sure if -draw supports the @textfile syntax. You have to be sure your text file is UTF-8 compatible. Notepad is not. I think Wordpad has an option for that, if on Windows. On Mac, I know that BBEdit if fine. I do not know Linux text editors.

Comment: `file --mime words.utf` gives `words.utf: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. I will try it in windows later

Comment: tried in windows with notepad++, still same result.

Comment: What are the keystrokes for the word or character with which you are having trouble. I will try it.

Comment: Why don't you copy the word from my question. If you want to type it you need to go to https://www.google.com/intl/ml/inputtools/try/ and type `utharam`.

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick 6.9.11.28 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra, the following label: command works just fine for me.

Perhaps your problem is the meera font you are using. I got mine from https://www.malayalamfont.com/download.php?id=867. Also check your version of freetype to be sure it is current. My version was 2.10.1

```
convert -size 100x -background white -font /Library/fonts/meera.ttf -fill black label:"ഉത്തരം" result.png
```

[image]

Also -annotate and -draw work:

```
convert -size 100x31 xc:white -gravity center -pointsize 28 -font /Library/fonts/meera.ttf -fill black -annotate +0+0 "ഉത്തരം" result.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 100x31 xc:white -gravity center -pointsize 28 -font /Library/fonts/meera.ttf -fill black -draw "text 0,0 'ഉത്തരം'" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: The text in image you got is **NOT** the desired one. It should look like `ഉത്തരം` and **NOT** `ഉത് തരം`

Comment: Copying your text "ഉത്തരം" does not produce the correct characters. Neither did using "utharam". What are the keystrokes you used? What is the real file name for your font?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check keystroke. If I want to have the word `ഉത്തരം` or any word in malayalam language I will go to https://www.google.com/intl/ml/inputtools/try/ and type it. There are lots of compound words in our language. For example `ചോദ്യം ട്രാൻസ്ജെൻഡർ ന് ക്രിക്കറ്റ് കളിക്കാൻ അനുവദിക്കുന്ന പുതിയ നിയമത്തിന് രൂപം നൽകിയ രാജ്യം ആസ്ത്രേലിയ`. In this sentence there is lots of compound letters. Just copy it and try it in your command. Font name is Meera, you will get it from https://smc.org.in/fonts/meera or try any other font from https://smc.org.in/fonts/

Comment: Ok, I got it. Go to https://help.keyman.com/keyboard/malayalam/1.1/chart#Technical  scroll to bottom. There is reference to keystroke

Comment: So the Keystroke for `ഉത്തരം` is `Gldljx`

Comment: That does not work for me in MS Word or BBEdit and I know my text editors are in UTF-8 mode. Do you need key combinations such as option along with the letters "Gldljx"? What was your exact font file name and where did you down load it?

Comment: No keycombination used. You can write "Gldljx" [here](https://kuttipencil.in/) which only work with computer, not in mobile or [here](https://www.branah.com/malayalam). You can download font from [here](https://smc.org.in/downloads/fonts/meera/meera.zip)

Comment: In Gist type `KghgjS` produce `ഉത്തരം`, In Inscript type `Gldljx` produce `ഉത്തരം`. In Typewritter type `Kf\fg~` and in Panchari `Py,ytJ` and inVarityper `Zd/d'r` gives `ഉത്തരം`. Please try all there keystrokes. And I think Meera font is unicode not utf-8

Comment: I do not use those tools. I am simply trying to type into a UTF-8 compatible text editor. None seem to recognize those characters. Unicode and UTF-8 are the same. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode So I need to know what keystrokes to type in a UTF-8 compatible text editor to reproduce your characters. What keystrokes do you need in Wordpad or Word.

Comment: Try this `Option+0D09
Option+0D24
Option+0D4D
Option+0D24
Option+0D30
Option+0D02`

Comment: You will get more info from [here](https://r12a.github.io/scripts/malayalam/)

Comment: Hi, Do you need more info?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the +0D09 on your Option+0D09. What key is that? When I typed `KghgjS`. I got that back. Let me download your font and try again.

Comment: No change. I still get `KghgjS`.

Comment: It works as follows. Open wordpad or ms word and set font to meera, then just type `0D09` select it and press `alt+x` in windows or linux, may be `option+x` in mac. It will produce `ഉ` and so on. I tried it in libre office in linux. And it works.

Comment: This is not the way that I can do it on a Mac. The keyboard has to be set up properly to press the option key and the numbers, which is what I have done. See Fun with Unicode section at https://tidbits.com/2016/07/11/os-x-hidden-treasures-typing-exotic-characters/

Answer (score 0):

I looked up how to type Option+0D09 Option+0D24 Option+0D4D Option+0D24 Option+0D30 Option+0D02 in my text editor. But what I get in the editor is not `ഉത്തരം`. It seems that pasting into this box changes what one sees.

What I see in my text editor is the same as what I get when I render it in ImageMagick. Are you sure your 3rd character set of code, `Option+0D4D`, is correct? I can verify that the utf codes are what I see in my text editor by looking them up using UnicodeChecker (for Mac). I note that these are UTF-16 characters.

```
convert -size 100x -background white -font /Library/fonts/Meera-Regular.ttf -fill black label:"ഉത്തരം" x1.png
```

[image]

Or saving what I type in my text editor to a file then doing:

```
convert -size 100x -background white -font /Library/fonts/Meera-Regular.ttf -fill black label:@hindi.txt x2.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

Here are the glyphs for the UTF character codes you specified. These are exactly what I get from ImageMagick as above.

0D09:

[image]

0D24:

[image]

0D4D:

[image]

Comment: Please watch this video with subtitles/caption ON. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yetvqJ8NiGk

Comment: When you type your characters, you get what I have. But when you close up the spaces, it changes. Something is not correct. Look up the UTF characters and the glyphs it produces and you will see that what I have is correct.

Comment: I created an issue in our unicode language support, see [here](https://github.com/smc/AnjaliOldLipi/issues/1). This font is AnjaliOldLipi, same as meera. I asked for sublime same happened to imagemagick. Also some info [here](https://r12a.github.io/scripts/malayalam/)

Comment: See my addition in my answer above.

Comment: I closed up spaces because it is auto added by libre office. Also I think Imagemagick/Sublime text3 does not support advanced text shaping. Because the problem fixed in vs code.

Comment: I do not use Sublime text3.  I used a Mac text editor with keyboard in Unicode mode. I do not understand why your youtube video show that when you remove spaces the characters change. I get what you type before you close up spaces. So I suspect something odd with your Libre Office.

Comment: You are getting correct words. May be imagemagick doesn't support advanced text shaping as indicated [here](https://github.com/smc/AnjaliOldLipi/issues/1)

Comment: It is not something odd with libre office, it is a feature. May be it is called advanced text shaping as indicated [here](https://github.com/smc/AnjaliOldLipi/issues/1)

Comment: I think Imagemagick may be lacking access to external shaping algorithms. See [here](https://github.com/r12a/scripts/issues/61)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221172/discussion-between-fmw42-and-justine-chacko).